# Display picture only if textbox is blank

Tags: c#, winforms

**My Program:** I have a textBox and a pictureBox (which contains an error picture, placed exactly next to textBox) in userControl in my program.

**My Goal:** I want to HIDE the picture in the pictureBox only if the user types text in the textBox. If the textBox is left blank, the image in the pictureBox should be shown.

[image]

I tried using errorProvider but I was totally lost because I am a newbie in C# Programming. There are many errorProvider examples online but all examples are using Form and I am trying to do it in UserControl. So, I thought I should try this method. Please can you help me with the code? Thanks for your help in advance.

**ANSWER:**

Sealz answer works! My program will be working offline. So, this one also works:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            //Show Picture
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //Hide Picture
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        }
```

Thanks everybody for looking at my question! You all are awesome. =)

Comment: Form or UserControl makes no difference here.

Comment: Use the TextChanged event of the TextBox control.  If the TextBox.Text Length is > 0 then hide the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IsNullOrEmpty`

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    //Show Picture
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "locationofimg";
}
else
{
    //Hide Picture
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "";
}
```

To get fancy with it.

On form_Load() set the picturebox to nothing

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "";
    }
```

Then in the Textbox Change Method

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
         pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "";
    }
    else
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "Image\Location.com.etc";
    }
}
```

This will make the box empty to start with no image and as you type it will pop up. If the boxes text is deleted fully the image will vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Just test if the textbox has any text, and set the property accordingly.

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = (textBox1.Text.Length > 0) ?
    "imagefile" : String.Empty;
```

If this needs to update dynamically, just perform this action in the textbox's `TextChanged` event.